# How to store user settings in windows rt app

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

Coming from a mobile background (Android/iOS) both OS's have something that you can hold application preferences (`SharedPreferences` in android and `NSUserDefaults` in iOS) like boolean's, int's, strings's ect. which are just key/value pairs that the user can set for polling intervals or turning off something in the app.

What is the equivalent to that in Windows RT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings` is a container where you can programmatically add/set key-value-pairs. Are you looking for that?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.ASPx